# Perl issue - If-Statement in OTRS Module

Tags: perl, if-statement

Actually I don't really know Perl, but now I need to change a snippet for OTRS.

To explain the context shortly, it's in the Module SystemMonitoring.pm of OTRS:

The System writes the values out of an E-Mail via regular expressions and saves in $1.
There are three relevant Elements: State, Host and Service.
Only in Element State I want to write the value out of $2. In case of Host and Service the informations comes from $1.

Here is the snippet:

```
        for my $Element (qw(State Host Service)) {

        next ELEMENT if $AlreadyMatched{$Element};

        my $Regex = $Self->{Config}->{ $Element . 'RegExp' };

        if ( $Line =~ /$Regex/ ) {
            # get the found element value
                    $Self->{$Element} = $1;

            # remember that we found this element already
            $AlreadyMatched{$Element} = 1;
        }
    }
```

I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Looking at what I guess is the full source (https://github.com/OTRS/SystemMonitoring/blob/master/Kernel/System/PostMaster/Filter/SystemMonitoring.pm), the StateRegExp, HostRegExp and ServiceRegExp only have one capture, so there will never be a $2.  What do you think $2 actually is?

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your reply!
The "State:" line looks like that: State: UP -> WARNING (PROBLEM) now I build a Regex which reads that line: \s*State:\s+(\w+)\s->\s+(\w+) actually I thought in $1 is now UP and in $2 is WARNING, istn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the regex is `\s*State:\s+(\w+)\s->\s+(\w+)` as mentioned by the OP.

In that case, you can simply test for the value of $Element.

`if ($Element eq 'State') {
    print $2;
}
else {
    print $1;
}`

or more concisely,

`print ($Element eq 'State') ? $2 : $1;`